# React table within table

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-table

I am new to react and implementing react tables. This is how the UI looks like:
[image]

Here is my component code:

```
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="right_col" role="main">
          <h2>Stock</h2>
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header"></div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <FormProvider
                form="inline"
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                onSubmitSuccess={() => this.setState({ editing: null })}
                initialValues={this.state.editing}
                enableReinitialize
              >
                {formProps => {
                  return (
                    <form onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit}>
                      <Table
                        columns={this.columns}
                        data={this.props.data}
                        defaultPageSize={5}
                      >
                      </Table>
                    </form>
                  );
                }}
              </FormProvider>
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

FormProvider contains this code:

```
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";

const toRenderProp = ({ children, ...rest }) => children(rest);
export default reduxForm()(toRenderProp);
```

Now what I want to do is to make the data in the `Name` column clickable. How to do that?  and then upon clicking that data, I want a nested table to show up with related data. How can I achieve that?

My react version is `16.13.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with cell clicks

Your option like this:

```
        {
          Header: "Name",
          accessor: "name",
          Cell: NameComponent
        },
```

and your NameComponent should be like this :

```
   function NameComponent({ value }) {
      return (
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            alert("value");
          }}
        >
          {value}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you tell me how can I pass the ID of the object instead of 'name'?